# Can someone please explain this proof of the non-separability of $\ell^ \infty$.

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $A=\{x_n : x_n \in \ell^\infty\}$ be any arbitrary countable subset $\ell^\infty$.

For each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, let $x_n = (a_{n_i})_{i=1}^{\infty}.$ Define $y=(b_i) \in \ell^\infty$ as $$
b_i = \begin{cases}a_{i_i} + 1& |a_{i_i}| \leq 1\\
0&  |a_{i_i}|>1\\\end{cases}$$

The $i$'th component of $y-x_i$ is $b_i - a_{i_i}$ and $|b_i - a_{i_i}| \geq 1$, hence $A$ cannot be dense in $\ell^\infty$.

I'd like to someone to explain why $|b_i - a_{i_i}| \geq 1$. This might be obvious, but I just don't see it.

Comment: That is not a proof of incompleteness (luckily, for the space *is* complete) but of non-separability.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez I'm sorry yes, I'll correct the mistake.

Answer (score 1):

If $|a_{i_i}| \leq 1$, then

$$|b_i - a_{i_i}| = |(a_{i_i} + 1) - a_{i_i}| = |1| = 1.$$

If $|a_{i_i}| > 1$, then

$$|b_i - a_{i_i}| = |0 - a_{i_i}| = |a_{i_i}| > 1.$$

Either way, we have $|b_i - a_{i_i}| \geq 1$.